# porque no puedo hacer conexion por duckdns a mi raspberry

Tags: raspbian, raspberry

tengo un raspberry pi 4, en el cual estoy tratando de configurar para ingresar a ella por desde fuera de mi red local, tengo instalado lo siguiente:

- Raspbian
- OpenMediaVault
- Portainer
- en portainer duckdns desde stack

puedo acceder al portal de OMV desde mi ip local, pero si ingreso la publica no entra, el stack de duckdns funciona bien, no muestra errores en el log, pero tampoco puedo ingresar a travez del subdomino que da duckdns, ya abri puertos en el firewall de mi modem 80, 433, 22 y aun asi sigo sin lograr la conexión desde internet hacia mi raspberry, ¿alguna sugerencia?, muchas gracias por adelantado, saludos.

[image: servidor virtual]

[image: aplicaciones especiales]

```
[cont-init.d] 99-custom-files: executing... ,
[custom-init] no custom files found exiting...,
[cont-init.d] 99-custom-files: exited 0.,
[cont-init.d] done.,
[services.d] starting services,
[services.d] done.,
[s6-init] making user provided files available at /var/run/s6/etc...exited 0.,
[s6-init] ensuring user provided files have correct perms...exited 0.,
[fix-attrs.d] applying ownership & permissions fixes...,
[fix-attrs.d] done.,
[cont-init.d] executing container initialization scripts...,
[cont-init.d] 01-envfile: executing... ,
[cont-init.d] 01-envfile: exited 0.,
[cont-init.d] 10-adduser: executing... ,
usermod: no changes,
,
-------------------------------------,
          _         (),
         | |  ___   _    __,
         | | / __| | |  /  \ ,
         | | \__ \ | | | () |,
         |_| |___/ |_|  \__/,
,
,
Brought to you by linuxserver.io,
-------------------------------------,
,
To support the app dev(s) visit:,
DuckDNS: https://www.patreon.com/user?u=3209735,
,
To support LSIO projects visit:,
https://www.linuxserver.io/donate/,
-------------------------------------,
GID/UID,
-------------------------------------,
,
User uid:    998,
User gid:    100,
-------------------------------------,
,
[cont-init.d] 10-adduser: exited 0.,
[cont-init.d] 40-config: executing... ,
Retrieving subdomain and token from the environment variables,
g will be output to file,
Your IP was updated at Fri Jul  2 03:04:05 UTC 2021,
[cont-init.d] 40-config: exited 0.,
[cont-init.d] 99-custom-files: executing... ,
[custom-init] no custom files found exiting...,
[cont-init.d] 99-custom-files: exited 0.,
[cont-init.d] done.,
[services.d] starting services,
[services.d] done.,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.duckdns.org,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.duckdns.org,
[s6-init] making user provided files available at /var/run/s6/etc...exited 0.,
[s6-init] ensuring user provided files have correct perms...exited 0.,
[fix-attrs.d] applying ownership & permissions fixes...,
[fix-attrs.d] done.,
[cont-init.d] executing container initialization scripts...,
[cont-init.d] 01-envfile: executing... ,
[cont-init.d] 01-envfile: exited 0.,
[cont-init.d] 10-adduser: executing... ,
usermod: no changes,
,
-------------------------------------,
          _         (),
         | |  ___   _    __,
         | | / __| | |  /  \ ,
         | | \__ \ | | | () |,
         |_| |___/ |_|  \__/,
,
,
Brought to you by linuxserver.io,
-------------------------------------,
,
To support the app dev(s) visit:,
DuckDNS: https://www.patreon.com/user?u=3209735,
,
To support LSIO projects visit:,
https://www.linuxserver.io/donate/,
-------------------------------------,
GID/UID,
-------------------------------------,
,
User uid:    998,
User gid:    100,
-------------------------------------,
,
[cont-init.d] 10-adduser: exited 0.,
[cont-init.d] 40-config: executing... ,
Retrieving subdomain and token from the environment variables,
g will be output to file,
Your IP was updated at Sat Jul  3 15:34:36 UTC 2021,
[cont-init.d] 40-config: exited 0.,
[cont-init.d] 99-custom-files: executing... ,
[custom-init] no custom files found exiting...,
[cont-init.d] 99-custom-files: exited 0.,
[cont-init.d] done.,
[services.d] starting services,
[services.d] done.,
```

Comment: ¿Configuraste en el router el Dynamic DNS o el Port Mapping? De lo contrario nunca vas a llegar a tu servidor con IP externa. La IP externa llega al router siempre y si no le configuras el Port Mapping como quieres que te redireccione a tu red interna.

Comment: Trae dos opciones para servicios, servidor virtual y aplicaciones especiales (en ambas están configurados los puertos y la ip fija), que según la documentación del modem es el equivalente a el port mapping

Comment: Y está en modo `bridge`? Yo tambien tengo un Pi4 e ingreso con la IP pública a Pi4  y lo único que tuve que configurar fue el Port Mapping. Puse por ejemplo: Puero entrada (visible desde red externa): 22  IP: Destino: 192.168.1.100 Puerto: 8922. El Pi4  está el SSH escuchando por el puerto 8922. Desde cualquier parte yo ingreso al Pi4 utilizando la IP externa puerto 22.  algo así 214.xxx.xxx.xxx:22 y ek router lo redirige. Fijate si tu router está en modo  `Bridge` (en gateway no funciona) y los port mapping. Me avisas y por el chat interno si quiere te envío como la configuración.

Comment: También en  una ocasión lo configuré como Dynamic DNS y me registré en `RemoteIt`para  utilizar una URL y nombre IP. Lo dejé porque como es free tenía  ciertas limitacion es.

Comment: Tengo un modem huawei de la compañía telcel , no tiene modos como, ap, bride, mirror, etc, pero lo uso como router, entonces ¿me recomiendas comprar  un router, hacer subred y sobre el mismo router configuro ?, ¿en el modem habría que abrir los mismos puertos? o ¿solamente se configura el router?

Comment: DIme la marca de tu modem para ver las características, porque  me  parece raro que tengas un modem y no un router. Si no tiene esas capacidades habría que ver que si compras un router lo puedas conectar a la red telcel. Por eso mandame que modelo de modem es.

Comment: HUAWEI B310s -518

Comment: Fijate si  en la consola de  configuración del router si tienes una opción `Virtual Servers`

Comment: claro, la tengo, ahí es donde comento que abrí los puertos  80,433 y 22

Comment: El pi4 tiene activos los puertos 80, 433 y 22? Si los tiene activos entonces los puertos externos deberían ser otros como por ejemplo 8080, 4443 y 2222 asociados a la IP externa. La configuración debería ser IP del pi4, puerto externo 8080 y puerto interno 80.!y con la IP externa te conectas la puerto 8080 y el router lo redireccionar al pi4 puerto 80.

Comment: Mira si tiene el Port fordward debe tener la opción de modo. Fíjate en la configuración de la WAN. Debe haber una opción de modo: debería estar en `puente` y la configuración cómo lo mencioné nateriorme t

Comment: con abrir puertos en la raspberry te refieres al firewall ufw ?

Comment: No, ponte que tengas el SSH, o un WebServer. Quieres conectarte al Pi4 a qué. Yo tengo en mi pi4 el SSH y un VPN escritorio Remoto, entonces estos dos puertos son lo que configuro en mi router y así puedo entrar desde cualquier lado a pi4 ya sea por SSH o por Conexion de escritorio Remoto

Comment: Ah, y tambien tengo un pi3 dónde tengo que un GIt Server y Plex Server que puedo conectarme también desde cualquier lado.

Comment: O mejor aún, puedes pegar la imagen la la pantalla de Virtual Server y de la Configuración WAN de tu Router en la pregunta?

Comment: perdón por la demora, el trabajo me tiene algo ocupado, no se que horario tengas así que, aproximadamente dentro de unas 8 horas te envío la configuración, estuve checando la documentación de portainer y usa iptables, ¿no se tiene que abrir puertos ahí ?

Comment: listo he editado el post con las imágenes de como están configurados mis puertos

Comment: Y la configuración de la WAN? Tacha si quieres los datos solo quiero ver  las opciones que tienes

Comment: Es preferible que la configuración de los puertos WAN sean diferentes. Por ejemplo: 8080 puerto WAN y 80 puerto LAN. El puerto 80 lo utiliza el router para su consola de configuración. Si le pones el 80 y 443 que son puertos que utiliza el router no creo que los redireccione. Prueba cambiando lo puertos WAN.

Comment: he cambiado lo que me comentas pero parece que no funciono, dejo el log de duckdns por si aporta mas información, mil gracias de antemano por todo tu apoyo

Comment: Esas Aplicaciones Especiales  puedes quitarlas y solo dejar los servidores virtuales?. Por otro  lado, un  dato importante que  olvidé mencionar el pi4 debe tener una IP estatica para que el router lo redireccione siempre a ese IP.

Comment: tiene ip estatica, pero para verificar podrias compartir tu dhcpd.conf para ver si tienes alguna variante que no estoy yomando en cuenta, ya elmine las aplicaciones especiales, sigo sin poder acceder ...

Comment: interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.2
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=200.***.***.***
static domain_search=200.***.***.***

Comment: El IP 192.168.1.2 es mi RaspBerry y el 192.168.1.1 es el router. los 200.* son los DNS

Comment: Ahi veo que no estas saliendo `www.duckdns.org` ¿el pi4 sale a internet sin problemas? Parece que no tiene salida.

Comment: ya solucione la salida del duckdns, tanto en la pagina como haciendo curl ifconfig.me desde la consola me tira el mismo ip, pero no entra, incluso poniendo la ip publica que se supone tiene asignada, la DNS de donde la sacas?

Comment: El DNS lo obtengo desde la consola de  administración del  router. Bueno, en mi telefono celular tambien tengo un App `Net Analyzer` que cuando estoy conectado  por Wifi en  mi  casa  me  sirve  para escanear los equipos  que están conectados al router  y de paso  me da información de mi conexión y allí veo los DNS que me asigna el router aparte si el pi tiene la  IP estatica asignada. Me ayudó a detectar un problema de conexión del pi puesto que otro  equipo tenia la misma IP asignado por el DFHCP. Tuve que poner  al pi en 192.168.1.2 y  los  rangos del DHCP a partir del 192.168.1.3.

Comment: Tu IP  pública con que número empieza? No vaya ser  que  tu proveedor Internet utilice NAT3